# Cleaner way to handle thrown exceptions from NS libraries in Swift assignments?

Tags: swift, exception

I'm using NSRegularExpression in my Swift code because it needs to run on older platforms. The factory method throws, so we need to trap the error - which does indeed occur in my code (I feed in some crazy patterns). I call it using:

```
let regex: NSRegularExpression
do {
   regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [.caseInsensitive])
} catch {
    return false
}
```

For handling optionals, Swift offers the `guard let` pattern which makes this much more clear and self-documenting as it exposes the variable to the enclosing scope and one-lines the logic. `guard case` is also useful. Is there some similar syntactic sugar for throws?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "cleaner", what is wrong with do/catch? If you don't care about the error you could use `if let` or `guard` together with `try?`.

Comment: I tried that (I realize I only intimated that in my post, was not explicit) which results in "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSRegularExpression'"

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean

```
guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(...) else { return false }
```

Comment: Ahhh, ? is allowed, ! is not. The error is returned is rather misleading.

Comment: No, it isn't misleading at all. They mean completely different things and the error message correctly describes what's wrong with `!` when used with `guard let`. Anyway there is no `!` in your question.